# How to find the exact number of bytes to allocate for a Solana Account in Rust

Tags: rust, account, rent

I want to create wallet account via Rust program by using payer & mint account, in that case how to predict the number of bytes to allocate for the new account data so that I can pay less rent ?

```
let space = spl_token::state::Account::get_packed_len(); //Number of bytes to allocate for the new account data    
let rent = rpc.get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(space)?; //Calculate min rent according to expected account data size

//Build instruction for create account 
let create_token_acc_ix = solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
    &payer_pubkey,
    &wallet_pubkey,
    rent,
    space as u64,
    &spl_token::ID,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find space for each type [HERE](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html#space-reference).

Answer (score 0):

use spl_token::state::Mint;
let space = Mint::LEN;

spl_token::state::Account::get_packed_len() gives you the wrong size.